# How to do unit test for SPContext in Sharepoint using VS 2010

Tags: c#-4.0

Here I am unit testing the share point code in visual studio 2010 but the thing is the code contains the SPContext for getting current url while testing we are passing static url so at that time when calling the method that using SPContext statement its throwing null reference exception. "**So can any one give me solution for this issue.....**"

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

http://sharepoint.nailhead.net/2008/04/test-driven-development-with-sharepoint.html

Comment: Dead link, not much use as an answer now :(